# Explicit interface implementation and Reflection.Emit

Tags: reflection.emit

Does anybody know how to implement an interface's property explicitly
using Reflection.Emit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation for [TypeBuilder.DefineMethodOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethodoverride.aspx), which includes an example of using Reflection.Emit to generate an explicit interface implementation using that method.

Answer (score 3):

This [Reflector Addin](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ReflectionEmitLanguage&referringTitle=Home) should help you.  It translates the IL code of a given method into the C# code that would be needed to generate the same IL code using `System.Reflection.Emit.`